# Eclipse keeps changing spell check engine

Tags: eclipse, latex, spell-checking

I am using Eclipse 3.6 and Texlipse 1.4.0. The spell checker works well with my own dictionary, however, completely randomly, when I either build my tex document or look at Java code editor my spell checker engine changes from my own to LaTex.

Is there anyway to stop this auto changing feature?

Thanks.

P.S.: Using Mac OS X 10.6.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [thread mentions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/forums/forum/451977/topic/3669794):

- that texlipse1.4.0 has somme issues with the spell checking feature
- might work better with eclipse3.5 (and Texlipse1.4.1) than Eclipse 3.6

This [other thread troubleshoot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/forums/forum/451977/topic/3889056) an inactive spell checker (not your case, but I mention it here just in case), again with Texlipse1.4.1

Can you reproduce the problem with 1.4.1? And with an Eclipse3.5?

Comment: I haven't tried the 1.4.1 with 3.5 configuration but 1.4.1 with 3.6 does not work. The spell checking is supposed to be there but for some reason it is not working for me. Thanks for pointing it out to me though.

Comment: Thanks! 3.6 and 1.4.1 and the proper settings with dictionaries at least allowed me to have a spell checker with latex spelling engine. I think this solves my problem; even if it changes I have spell checking with both engines.